# Store node_modules into BitBucket for a build with npm install

Tags: git, npm, bitbucket, npm-install

Our corporate policies do not allow us to do a build via the internet using "npm install". Looking at the documentation for [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) it seems that a Git (in our case BitBucket) repository that contains the node_modules can be specified. Can someone point me to a guide (or give me some friendly advice) on how the repository is setup and configured to not only manage builds for the current state of the package.json but also for past releases and going in to the future as the node_modules content changes. What is in this repository? Thanks!

Comment: How about cloning the required repos and pointing the dependency value your cloned repo in package.json.https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies.

Comment: I once wanted to use a git repo but it was not on npm, I forked it and added a package.json and in the "main" field I specified the name of the source file I wanted to run when i "required" it and my actual project depended on the forked git repo. It served me well. You can find all you need in the link I specified in my previous comment. Good luck !